# Writing Hrefs to CSV file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Having Trouble writing to a CSV file. Code as Below. the Set is writing on the same row when I go to write it into "fofo" file

```
response = requests.get(href)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

This opens the "shomo" file with existing Hrefs
with open('shomo.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    seen = {row[0] for row in reader}

allthreads=soup.find('table', class_='categories').find_all('p')
for thread in allthreads:
    thread_link= thread.a.get('href')
    #Checks if Link is in "Seen"
    if thread_link not in seen:

        seen.add(thread_link) #Add new href to Seen
        thread_data = scrape_thread_link(thread_link) #Calls function 

   #Having trouble with this part
    with open('fofo.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows([seen])
```

The code without opening a previous file and adding to the Seen the code prints prefect fine as below: 
not sure what is different/ wrong?

```
import csv
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

response = requests.get('https://website.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
seen = set ()

with open('momo.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    allthreads=soup.find('table', class_='categories').find_all('p')
    for thread in allthreads:
        #thread_name = thread.text
        #print (thread_name)
        thread_link= thread.a.get('href')
        if thread_link not in seen:
            seen.add(thread_link)
            writer.writerows([seen])
```

Comment: You haven't show the issue that you're facing. You just state that something is wrong.

Comment: What problem are you having? I would use a list instead of a set for storing data. Can you give us the data format you are getting out of the table?

Comment: @roganjosh oops haha fixed. When writing to "fofo" it is writing all the href into the same row.

Comment: @TenaciousB I am getting hrefs. from the "shomo" file.  I am using set b/c there are duplicate hrefs.

Comment: are you just trying to write a list of links or is there another column you want in the csv? I still don't understand what problem you are having. Are you trying to append the new links to an existing csv?

Comment: @TenaciousB basically I want to get an already existing set of links (hrefs) from the file "shomo" and add to it with whatever new UNIQUE links I get from running this program. it can be either 1.) added to shomo or 2.) saved in a new file (like it is doing right now, I would prefer option 1 but will take option 2 if thats less code/easier...

Comment: Use a mode to append to the file.